# Include Pods from Swift Sources in iOS7 Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a iOS7 Swift project and want to use a pod like [this](https://github.com/naoty/Timepiece) which is based on Swift code.

In my pod file I can include the pod like this:

```
platform :ios, "7.0"
pod "Timepiece"
```

Assume that the project runs on iOS.How can I include pods from Swift sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only choice is to manually insert source code into your project, because:

1. It is not possible to build static libraries from Swift code.
2. Thus Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as dynamic frameworks
3. You cannot have dynamic frameworks before iOS 8.

Comment: Ok, so when i have a Swift pod can I just copy the Swift code in my project and I am done or is there anything else to do?

Comment: Yes, you can just drop files into the project and you are good to go. In most cases..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do same as `iOS` `pod`, just `#import` all `.h` files in `bridge.h` file and Use  `Objective-C bridging header` by selecting your `Target - >Build Setting -> Swift compiler - code generation`.

Just drag you `bridge.h` file from your project to `Swift compiler - code generation` section.

Check out [THIS](https://medium.com/@kirualex/cocoapods-with-swift-e6f8ba8f0afc) standard tutorial for more details.
May this help you !!

Comment: I said that there is only Swift code. I do not need a bridging header.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are trying to.
Cocoapod is a dependency manager.
When you create a pod file in the same folder of your .xcodeproj, and run "pod install" at the the folder  through the terminal,
an .xcworkspace will be crated.
Then you can use the pod project with your project by opening the .xcworkspace file instead of .xcodeproj

reference:https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html